# How to Set BackColor of Inactive Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backcolor

I have a form that contains several Textboxes and Comboboxes. I have set active control's back color property to skyblue. I want to set the back color of all textboxes and comboboxes to white while they are not active.

Comment: you mean by inactive as not focused or enabled=false?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Right Way and a *wrong way* to do this.  You are asking for the wrong way.  The right way is to derive your own class from TextBox and override the OnEnter and OnLeave methods.  Repeat for ComboBox.

But you ask for the wrong way and you are probably trying to add this feature too late so we'll have to slug it out by finding the controls back at runtime.  Add a constructor to your form class and make it look like:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    FindControls(Me.Controls)
End Sub

Private Sub FindControls(ctls As Control.ControlCollection)
    For Each ctl As Control In ctls
        Dim match As Boolean
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBoxBase Then match = True
        If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
            Dim combo = DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox)
            If combo.DropDownStyle <> ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList Then match = True
        End If
        If match Then
            AddHandler ctl.Enter, AddressOf ControlEnter
            AddHandler ctl.Leave, AddressOf ControlLeave
        End If
        FindControls(ctl.Controls)
    Next
End Sub

Private controlColor As Color

Private Sub ControlEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    controlColor = ctl.BackColor
    ctl.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
End Sub

Private Sub ControlLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    ctl.BackColor = controlColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't enough just add event handlers for `Enter` and `Leave` events for controls we want without deriving controls and without `FindControl`? In the constructor for example

Comment: Sorry, why it is error-prone way. What disadvantages in this way?(except one: need add event handlers for every form in the project if you want same behavior in all forms)).

Comment: You'll just plain overlook a control, particularly one that's nested in a container.  Note how FindControls uses recursion.  And you'll always forget a year or two from now.  And it's slave labor, outlawed by the Geneva Convention on Programmer's Rights.